# Can't build vibed: dmd failed with exit code 255

Tags: d, vps, vibed

I am trying to build vibed app of VPS. And I am getting error:
`dmd failed with exit code 255`.

Here is full log:

```
Compiling source/app.d...
Compiling source/dbconnect.d...
Compiling source/draft/database/collection.d...
Compiling source/draft/database/database.d...
Compiling source/draft/database/package.d...
Compiling source/draft/database/storage.d...
Compiling source/globals.d...
Compiling source/parseconfig.d...
Compiling source/users.d...
Compiling source/variantconfig.d...
Compiling ../../../../root/.dub/packages/vibe-d-0.7.30-alpha.1/vibe-d/source/vibe/appmain.d...
Linking...
cc: No such file or directory
--- errorlevel 255`
```

google do not know nothing about this error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have GCC installed on that VPS? As far as I remember, DMD uses the GCC linker under the scenes to do the linking. From the error message, it looks like it is not installed...
Depending on the type of VPS (Debian based, Redhat, etc), you need to install GCC.

For Debian based distro, something like:

> apt-get install build-essential

should get you going. Refer the documentation for your specific distro to install GCC if not on a Debian derivative.

Hope this helps...

Comment: I installed it, but get next error:
`Linking...
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lsqlite3
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lpq
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -levent_pthreads
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lssl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lcrypto
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
--- errorlevel 1
dmd failed with exit code 1.
`

Comment: Ah, now you are missing some dependencies:
- sqlite3
- ssl
- event
So same idea: install the missing packages. On Debian: `apt-get install libsqlite3-0 libssl1.0.0 libevent-openssl-2.0-5`